# Rspec ignore routing constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I wrote most of my Rspec specs, but I'm facing one important problem. I've set a routing constraint on all my routes (which by itself might be debatable). Only administrators which have allowed Ip-addresses (that are stored in a separate IpAddress model) can access certain areas in my application.

Long story short, I want to mock or stub my constraint model so that I can freely access everything within my specs.

My constraint looks like this:

```
class IpAddressConstraint
  def initialize
    @ips = IpAddress.select('number')
  end

  def matches?(request)
    if @ips.find_by_number(request.remote_ip).present? || Rails.env.test? #<- temporary solution
      true
    else
      if @current_backend_user.present? 
        backend_user_sign_out 
      else
        raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
      end
    end
  end
end

MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints IpConstraint.new do
    #all routes
  end
end
```

What is the best way I can test this routing constraint in Rspec? Currently I've added a conditional so that if I'm in my test environment I could just skip these constraints altogether. It would be better if I could somehow simulate this constraint.

Comment: add 127.0.0.1/32 to your list of allowed IPS? assuming you are using something like capybara?

Comment: I have a seperate model for IPs, but that is only accessible by logging in. It would be nice if I could write a helper in which I could create a new Ip_address.number (127.0.0.1 in my case). It could be a poor design decision though to have such a firm constraint.

Comment: you have a model for IPs called IpAddress.  All you need to do is something like  `IpAddress.create(number: '127.0.0.1')` prior to any specs that are going through the routes. You wouldn't need to create that Object/record via its controller / etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
describe "Some Feature" do

context "from allowed ip" do
  before(:each) {IpAddress.create(number: '127.0.0.1')} 

   it "should allow access to foo" do 
     ..... 
   end

    ....
end

context "from non allowed ip" do 
  it "shouldn't allow access to foo" do 
     ..... 
  end
end
```

Then you could extract the the IP address create to either A helper module or a function especially if you need to do more complex setup.   IF you always wanted it to be there you could add it in your spec_helper file config block to run before each/every spec, but then you would have a harder time testing that it successfully blocks non authorized ips.

Comment: This solution seems pretty straightforward. Actually, I think I've already tried this but still ran into some problems. Might have been a type tough, I will check it again on monday (I have that application only at work). If this solution works I will accept your answer. I don't really like my temporary solution to just skip the routing constraint in my test environment altogether.

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work (famous last words). But if you do run into issues, include them, and perhaps we can help.

Comment: Let's hope your right. If I will run into any issues I will post my error logs.

Comment: Just ran all tests and it works. I guess I had my login helper method before I created the IpAddress, therefor the login failed (breaking all my specs). Thank you for your help, I've accepted the answer.